# scope angular-modal and angular-timer directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timer, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to get the same timer in the view and in the modal. 
Both work with the same scope:

```
$scope.openTimer = function() {
var modalInstance = null;
modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'modal-timer.html',
  controller: 'ModalTimerController',
  scope: $scope,
  backdrop: 'static',
  size: "sm"
});
modalInstance.result.then(function() {
  console.log('onCloseModal');
});
}
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4rkMkOs4jYvWmX7eOoF?p=preview).

The problem I have is that I can't share the running time (coming from timer directive) between the view and the modal. The modal always opens with reset timer.

Is there any way to share exactly the same timer running time in view and modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a service for your timer functionality.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

I would move all of your functions on the scope out to a service, and then only use the scope to display the current time.  In this way, you could inject the service into the controller, and the controller would only be responsible for displaying the information.  A service is a singleton, meaning that there is only one instance of it, and it is just passed around wherever you inject it.  So whatever state it is at would be shared between any controller that it is injected into.

It would look something like this (where TimeService holds the code currently in your controller):

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', 'TimeService',
  function($scope, $element, TimeService) {
    $scope.timeDisplay = TimeService.currentTime;
  }
]
```

Of course, you'd have to write the service, and have it's calculations assign a value to currentTime.

Comment: I did what you said and used [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2674-creating-a-reusable-timer-in-angularjs.htm) to help me to implement it correctly. Everything works as I want. I start implementing an other directive/service timer for angular [here](http://louisamoros.github.io/angular-timer/#/home).